# How can I get the counter of matches inside nested foreach loop?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, nested-loops

I'm trying to get the number of matches inside a nested foreach loop, but the counter is constantly set at 0. How can I solve it?

```
my $file_counter = 0;
checkFilesInDirectory($den_file_input, $array_regex_tot, $expected_file_num);
sub checkFilesInDirectory {
    my ($dir_path, $array_reg, $expected_file_number) = @_;
    opendir (DIR, $dir_path)  or die "Can't open $dir_path: $!";
    my @file = readdir(DIR);
    foreach my $file (@file) {
      foreach my $regex (@array_regex) {
        if ($file =~ $regex) {
            $file_counter++;
        }
      } 
    }

    if ($file_counter < $file_previsti) {
        print "\nKO All'interno di $dir_path non e presente il numero di file previsti ($file_previsti).\n";
        # &ExitWithError($msg);
    } elsif ($file_counter == $expected_file_number) {
        print "\nOK " . substr(gmtime(time()), 11, 8) . "\n";
        # &ExitWithSuccess($msg);
    } elsif ($file_counter > $expected_file_number) {
        print "\nWARNING All'interno di $dir_path sono presenti piu di file ($file_counter)         di quelli previsti ($file_previsti).\n";
        # &ExitWithSignal($msg);
    }
    closedir(DIR);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have your code in the question run stand-alone. The fact you're reading a directories and testing files doesn't really matter. You can make `@file` a static list for the example, and also include your `@array_regex` with simple patterns (like `qw(foo bar bz)`) to demonstrate what the problem is. [Edit] your question to make these changes. It'll help us run your code to reproduce the problem, and you _might_ find the problem yourself while trying to reproduce it.

Comment: If the counter stays at 0, there probably isn't a match. Stick some `print` statements for debugging into that loop and the `if` block, and turn `re 'debug'` on to see if it runs and matches. You are also not using `$array_reg`.

Comment: You have declared `$file_counter` outside of your sub, so basically you are accessing a global variable. If you run this sub twice, you will get wrong results. Put the declaration inside the sub, and use `return $file_counter` to get the count.

Comment: Also, `@array_regex` is not declared anywhere. You pass a scalar `$array_reg` to the sub, but you never use it.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give detailed advice without seeing more of your code. But one thing jumps out at me: When you're unpacking `@_` at the start of your subroutine, you put the second parameter into a scalar variable called `$array_reg`; but you don't use that variable anywhere in your code and, instead, when you're iterating over a list of regexes, you use an array variable called `@array_regex`. Should this be `@$array_reg` instead? Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code? It's always a good idea to add them as they will point out errors like this.

I'm also puzzled as to why you declare `$file_counter` outside of your subroutine. When using subroutines (in any language - not just Perl), it's a good rule of thumb that a subroutine should never access variables that are defined outside of the subroutine. If you need to access that data inside the subroutine, then pass it as an extra parameter. If you want to update that variable, then return the next value from your subroutine.